# Rails and highcharts (data to highcharts)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

Trying to build a standard stock chart but have no joy sending data to highcharts. Tried Chartkick with no joy as no grouping or summing required
Just plain date and price. The issue is sending the data to highcharts and cant seem to crack this.

Rails 4.5

```
gem 'highcharts-rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.5'
```

Application js

```
//= require highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
```

In controller action

```
def action
 @rates_hash = @code.rates.each do |rate|
 date = rate.day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
 rates_hash[date] = rate.price.to_i
end
```

In helper

```
def data_series(rates_hash)
    dates = (rates_hash.keys.min..rates_hash.keys.max).to_a

    dates.map do |date, value|
    js_date = "Date.UTC(#{date.year}, #{date.month - 1}, #{date.day})"
    "[#{js_date}, #{rates_hash[date].to_i}]"
    end
end
```

In my view

```
<div id="graph" class="graph" data-rates="<%= @rates_array %>">

<script type="text/javascript">

const data = [<%= data_series(@rates_hash).join(",") %>];

Highcharts.stockChart('graph', {

title: {
text: 'USD-ZAR'
 },

xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime'
  title: {
          text: 'Date'
  }
},

yAxis: {
    crosshair: true
    title:  {
              text: 'Pain level'
            },
    tooltip: {
              headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
              pointFormat: '{point.y}'
              },
    },

rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1
},

  series: [{
      name: 'Rates',
      data: data
    }]
});
```

Model is: rates

```
class CreateRates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rates do |t|
      t.date        :day
      t.references  :code,      index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.decimal     :price,     :precision  =>  14, :scale => 6
    end
   end
 end
```

The error I get is: undefined local variable or method `rates_hash'
Help appreciated. Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use chartkick and do a private method in the controller

```
private

def set_rates(code_id)
  @rates.inject({}) do |new_element, current_element|
    day = current_element.day
    price = current_element.price
    new_element[day] = price
    new_element 
  end
end
```

This worked well just rather prefer to use plain highcharts